# Which file we should upload to server .scss or .css when we use Sass?

Tags: css, compass-sass, sass

Which file we should upload to server .scss or .css when we use Sass?

I read about Sass and Compass it makes these folders and files

[image]

I write scss in which gives output in .css file of same name.

My question do i need update whole folder to FTP or just .css file.?

I work with both .net and .php based websites.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the css is what the html pages will refer to.  So thats the one you need to upload.

For source control, you only really need to keep the sass.

Comment: we don't need to upload .sass-cache, sass folder and config.rb file to ftp?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not intend to do the compiling job on the server (like many Rails developers did with Capistrano), then no need to upload any sass files onto it. As Keith suggested, you need to keep sass files in source control repository and upload the css files. It's just like (more or less) compiling a c source code into binary executive files.