# Using SASS on remote server

Tags: css, sass

I am just getting started using SASS which is awesome. I dont develop on my localhost. I use Komodo and work directly off remote files from an external server. How do I go about using SASS in this way? Without having to use my localhost for it. I cant seem to find a way around this

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: As it stands, this question is a pretty broad. Do you want to compile your Sass on the server or on your machine? What kind of machine is each? Do you have any automation set up on either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Codekit. It lets you add folders to be "watched" and compiled. I use ExpanDrive for mounting my remote server and edit with SublimeText, but I'm sure you can do something similar with Komodo.

Answer (score 0):

I found this as answer to this problem. Compile on local server and only upload css files to remote server is the just of it

[Which file we should upload to server .scss or .css when we use Sass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845526/which-file-we-should-upload-to-server-scss-or-css-when-we-use-sass?rq=1)